# An error occurred while installing ruby-2.0.0

Tags: ruby, heroku, version

I did the following:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 72, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (61/61), done.
Writing objects: 100% (62/62), 91.66 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 62 (delta 40), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-16/ruby-2.0.0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 1 of 3.
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-16/ruby-2.0.0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 2 of 3.
remote:  !
remote:  !     An error occurred while installing ruby-2.0.0
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:  !     
remote:  !     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby version see:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
remote:  !     
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Debug InformationCommand: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-16/ruby-2.0.0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
remote:  !     tar: Child returned status 1
remote:  !     tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to ma-engtech.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/ma-engtech.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/ma-engtech.git'
```

I have a problem. I think it's because of the ruby version, but I am not sure how to solve it. Someone help me on this please.

Comment: Did you try visiting the link the error message?

Comment: @jordanm $ gem env version
2.6.14
nour@nours-MacBook-Air ~/ma-engtech [master]$ rails --version
Array values in the parameter to `Gem.paths=` are deprecated.
Please use a String or nil.
An Array ({"GEM_PATH"=>["/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2", "/Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global"]}) was passed in from bin/rails:3:in `load'
Rails 4.1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby 2.0.0 is very old, and not supported on Heroku anymore. You need to upgrade to a more recent version.

You can see all the supported ruby versions here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes

Comment: Ok I upgraded to ruby 2.3.4 and still have the same error!

Comment: The Heroku documentation is clear though: 2.3.4 isn't supported. 2.3.7 is.

Comment: I upgrade the ruby version to 2.3.7 by using this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsNXc3uQ2AA Thank you so much @damien

Comment: 'supported' or not, Heroku DOES install ruby 2.0.0 when using Cedar-14, so the buildpack is there, so why not when the stack is changed to Heroku-16?

Comment: It's not just about the buildpack being there. The ruby version has to be compiled for that stack too (to speed up builds, ruby is compiled once and only downloaded when you deploy your app).